# How should I structure .net website to use a web api?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm starting a project that will use a search bar to hit a web api and return the results. There will be no writing to the web api.

My biggest struggle when creating a new project is how it should be laid out. I never know when i should create a DAO, do it all via javascript, put it in a controller, etc.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more about the project?If you are talking about software architecture design, you should look into design patterns

Comment: You maybe want to look into [Separation of Concerns (SoC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: @rinukkusu thanks, I learnt something new today about software design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For developing something like a search engine or any web application. You would need following:

1. A frontend, which is your application's GUI in browser of user or mobile application.
2. A backend logic, this could be in any server side scripting language, in your case you would be writing server code in .net

Now, your backend must expose a search api, Eg. If I send a `HTTP GET` with a variable `q`, it should return search results matching the query.

Your frontend must have `input-box` and a `button` for allowing users to send this request.

This answer isn't complete, just a vague overview of how this problem can be approached, also this isn't the only solution.

Comment: I am going to be writing the front-end portion of this. I am going to be hitting a URL with the parameters from the search box and that will be returning JSON data to me. Is it best to simply use AJAX for this? Is there even a point in making a MVC .net application if I won't really be using the models or controllers? Thanks :)

Comment: You can use something like AngularJS which is an MVC framework and is very powerful for things like DOM manipulation, custom directives etc. Otherwise, you can always use plain old js to make an ajax call and return some `JSON`. MVC is a design pattern, it's not mandatory, but a good practice.